# Rendering additional HTML in FireFox causes slight hang

Tags: jquery, html, css, ajax, firefox

Ok, so I've got a wierd problem.

I am loading in some HTML via AJAX, which effectively renders as a modal. It's just a straightforward AJAX load, and appending it to the body.

Works fine in Chrome, however in Firefox there is a slight hang before I can interact with anything (including right-click, or highlighting text or anything!)

All the JavaScript does is:

```
       $.get("<?php echo $this->getUrl("b2b/index/addconfigurable"); ?>",{
           pid: $(this).attr('data-pid')
       },function(res){
           $("body").append(res);
        jQuery(".closemodalx,.closemodal").click(function(){
        jQuery(".viewproductmodal").fadeOut(function(){
            jQuery(".viewproductmodal").remove();
        })
        });
       },'html')
```

And the HTML that is produced is equally straighforward:

```
<div class='viewproductmodal'>
    <div class='closemodalx'>X</div>

        <div class='addconfblock'>
        <h2>Product Name</h2>
    <form action="/formurl/" method="post" id="product_addtocart_form" > enctype="multipart/form-data" target='ajaxframe'>        

    <div class='addblock'>

    <div class='closemodal'>Continue Shopping &nbsp; ></div>
    <div class='available'></div>
    <input type='text' name='qty' />
    <button type="submit" title="Add to Cart" class="button btn-cart"><span><span>Add to Cart</span></span></button>
    </div>
</form>

</div>
    <iframe name='ajaxframe' src='about:blank' style='border:0;width:0px;height:0px;'></iframe>    

</div>
```

So I'm not sure what's causing the slight lag - does anyone have any experience of this, and is there any way around it?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have any plugin like FireBug running? I have seen that it can cause a slight lag for certain updates.

Comment: Too many variables to list from browser add-ons to page size issues to memory use to.....I wouldn't expect a simple answer except that Chrome is generally faster. Try in safe mode as comparison

Comment: Same As @charlietfl. Maybe it will be better just loading the `Product Name` `product Id` etc.. keeping the modal in the DOM and just changing the text and values -> this will be allot easier for the browser to repaint.